# Is it possible to stream audio to a live Twilio phone call?

Tags: twilio, call, audio-streaming

Is it possible to feed a live twilio phone call with a audio stream from a url?
This audio stream should then be played back to the caller. For clarification: I do not want the stream of the call itself (using twiMLs `<Stream>`), nor do I want to playback a fixed audio file (using twiMLs `<Play>`), I would rather like to play from a stream to the caller.

Comment: This is not possible.